Create a Custom R Layer with rpy2 on AWS Lambda
I am working on a Python Flask API that uses an R machine learning model via the rpy2 library. When I try accessing the deployed Python Flask API, it results in a "NoneType object failure" error. So, I need to create a custom AWS Lambda layer that includes both R and rpy2. However, I'm encountering an issue during the Docker container build, which says "rpy2 in API mode cannot be built without R in the PATH or R_HOME defined." I would appreciate any guidance, documents, or examples to resolve these issues!
I tried building a custom AWS Lambda layer using a Docker container to include R and the rpy2 library. I expected the Docker container to successfully build the environment and allow the Flask API to work with my R model. However, the Docker build fails with an error about rpy2 not finding R in the PATH or R_HOME defined, and when I try to run the API after deployment, I get a "NoneType object failure" error. I have ensured that R is installed in /usr/local/bin/R on my host machine, but it seems the path isn’t recognized properly in the Docker environment.
